# How to fetch only certain rows from an MySql database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php array of "primary key" values, which correspond to just a few rows of a very long table of data, saved on a MySql database.
How can I fetch with just one query only those rows. Is it possible or will I need to make one query per primary key? `eg: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE key = 8573`

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Don't forget to add an index for your table. Running a query on a "long table of data" is expensive. Considere adding this: alter table table1 add index (key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select * from table WHERE primary_key IN (8573,8574,8578)
```

for your php array you could use implode

```
$key_array = implode(",", $array);

Select * from table WHERE primary_key IN ($key_array)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use MySQL's [IN() operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

```
... WHERE x in (1,4,9,16)
```

Comment: IN is a bit of a SQL silver bullet that too many coders don't use either because they don't know about it or forget it exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from table1 WHERE key IN ([values separated by commas])
```

Answer (score 2):

On most databases, "key IN (set)" works faster than "key=a or key=b or...".

Specifically for PHP, you may use implode to generate your SQL:

$SQL = "select * from table where key in (".implode(',', $KeyArray)).")"

Assuming integer key. With a string key, you need to quote them:

$SQL = "select * from table where key in ('".implode("','", $KeyArray))."')"

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

```
select * from table1 where key in (8573, 5244, 39211);
select * from table1 where key = 8573 or key = 5244 or key = 39211;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the OR statement.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE key=8573 OR key=9999;
```

Of course this can get really long, so you'll probably want to use a loop and concatenate the keys to the query string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE primaryKey IN ('" . implode("','", $keys) . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this form of select

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE key IN (1234, 1235, 6789, 9876)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php's implode function:

```
$keys = array(1,2,3,4);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE key IN ( " . implode($keys, ",") . ")";
```