# SQL to only fetch some rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It was some time ago I worked with `PHP, MySQL and SQL,` so I need some help. In my table I have 44 rows, but I only want to get 24 of them. Before I have just loaded all the rows like in the code below, and now I need some help to modify it to only load 24 rows. Thanks!

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableObject} {$sort1};";

$res = $mysqli->query($query);

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($res);

while($row01 = $res->fetch_object()) {
// Some other code here
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch only certain rows from an MySql database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924442/how-to-fetch-only-certain-rows-from-an-mysql-database-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your query:

```
LIMIT 24
```

**LIMIT** is a MySQL function that selects a particular range of results from your query results. There are basically two ways of using it:

1. By simply specifying the number of results you want to fetch, like `LIMIT 24`; or
2. By specifying another range in the form of `LIMIT X, Y`. Where `X` is the beginning and `Y` is number of rows you want to fetch, like: `LIMIT 10,5` that would select the 5 results from row `11` to `15`

In your particular case you can simply replace this line:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableObject} {$sort1};";
```

For:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableObject} {$sort1} LIMIT 24;";
```

or even:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableObject} {$sort1} LIMIT 0,24;";
```

For a better understanding about how to use limit, I recommend you to read this page from [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/limit-optimization.html)

Comment: If an answer is correct please mark it as so. Otherwise StackOverflow will never know that your problem has been solved. Consider to upvote answers that were somewhat useful, doing so you can help other with the same question as yours to find an answer quickly

Comment: I know, but I have to whait some minutes

Comment: Oh ok, it's just that I copy paste this for every question from new users. I'm glad I could help. Cheers